# Basic energy changes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy

Please could someone explain in detail the energy changes in:-

an object projected upwards
• a moving object hitting an obstacle
• an object accelerated by a constant force
• a vehicle slowing down
• bringing water to a boil in an electric kettle

Please make your answers precise as vague answers to questions like these are not helpful.

Comment: This seems like a homework question.

Comment: Does that mean you won't help? It is still physics and sometimes it is surprising how simple things can lead to new learnings

Comment: Also-I will make my question more specific so its not a 'homework question'

Comment: I don't understand the energy changes in an object accelerated by a constant force

Comment: i understand that it gains kinetic energy but where exactly does it come from?

Comment: No, we'll still help, but we need to notify the site that it's a homework question, as there are regulations in place to make sure that we're not just doing someone's homework for them. I've already made the necessary changes.

Comment: could you answer it then please

Comment: As for your more specific question, if an object is being accelerated by a constant force, the thing that is providing the force is transferring energy to the object.

Comment: but what energy is converted to kinetic energy?

Comment: Whatever energy was being used to generate the force. If the force is a weight, then gravitational potential energy is used. If the force is an electric motor, then electrical potential energy is used. If the force is a spring, then elastic potential energy is used. If the force is a human, then chemical potential energy is used. The beautiful thing is that a force is a force is a force - all of these will give the same motion for the same amount of energy transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you need to know that work and energy can be inter converted.

Also work done by a constant force => $W = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{d}$

And Kinetic Energy = $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$

So by the Work-Energy Equivalence Theorem,

Kinetic Energy = Work Done by Constant Force
$\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{d}$